# Disable OnPaintBackground without subclassing Panel?

Tags: c#, winforms, paint, doublebuffered

Is there any way to disable the erasing of a panel without subclassing Panel and overriding OnPaintBackground?

I am trying to achieve a double buffering effect without subclassing Panel. I understand that this may be a weird thing to try to do, but I'd at least like to know if I can or not. The following code sample illustrates this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Bitmap m_image;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        panel1.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(panel1_Paint);
        panel1.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(panel1_MouseMove);

        m_image = new Bitmap(panel1.Width, panel1.Height);
    }

    void panel1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(m_image))
        {
            g.FillEllipse(Brushes.Black, new Rectangle(e.X, e.Y, 10, 10));
        }
        panel1.Invalidate();
    }

    void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(m_image, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

This causes a flickering, presumably because it is erasing the panel at each paint cycle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can hack OnPaintBackground() or you can hack WndProc().  Either requires deriving your own class.  It's trivial, I just don't see why you'd avoid it.  The long distance shot is SetWindowsHookEx() with a WH_CALLWNDPROC hook, too silly really.

Comment: Part of the reasoning for wanting to avoid deriving my own class is to have the ability to draw double buffered graphics on any Panel object, i.e. I want to attach to some existing Panel instead of replacing it with a custom control. It sounds like there isn't a nice way to do what I want though.

Comment: With WndProc you will not have much luck. Many controls paint their background in WM_PAINT rather than in WM_ERASEBACKGROUND. (Because it is flickerless) So hooking WM_ERASEBACKGROUND will be useless and when you hook WM_PAINT your code will have to draw the background and the entire control!

Comment: Hmm, no, it is a Panel.

Answer (score 0):

Just add:

```
panel1.BackgroundImage = m_image;
//on panel1_Paint() function.
```

Simple isn't it?

Comment: This is useless. If there is a Label or a CheckBox, RadioButton or any other control on the panel it will still draw it's own (grey) background.

Answer (score 0):

Use reflection to the set the protected DoubleBuffered property:

```
System.Reflection.PropertyInfo aProp =
         typeof(System.Windows.Forms.Control).GetProperty(
               "DoubleBuffered",
               System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic |
               System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);

aProp.SetValue(panel1, true, null);
```

You can also make it more efficient by only invalidating the changed area (this is almost flicker-free even without the double-buffering):

```
void panel1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Rectangle r = new Rectangle(e.X, e.Y, 10, 10);
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(m_image))
    {
        g.FillEllipse(Brushes.Black, r);
    }
    panel1.Invalidate(r);
}
```